# printing iteration of List

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying ot print out the values in a List but all that is produced is `false`. I am not sure why this is occurring.

code:

```
    List<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    coins.add(4);
    coins.add(14);
    coins.add(2);
    coins.add(33);
    coins.add(2);
    coins.add(7);
    coins.add(56);
    coins.add(5);
    coins.add(8);

    for (Integer j : coins) {
        System.out.println(coins.get(j));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it produces false"?

Comment: Can you clarify *what* produces `false`? Nothing should return false here.

Comment: it says false in my console

Comment: Does it still say false when you comment out the foreach loop?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yes, I tried `System.out.println(coins.get(1));` to get the value at index 1

Comment: If it still says `false` after removing the loop then the problem is not in the loop but somewhere else.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I thought I was iterating correctly but since I am new at Java I wasn't sure. I tried all the methods that the people posted but I am getting an output of false and I have no idea why

Comment: Please consider the Java API for iterations and lists, it is fairly clear what the method `List#get(int index)` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Integer j : coins) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it still produces false

Comment: @Liondancer: if it does, then you're not executing the right class, or you're executing an old different version of it.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you explain what you mean by an old  different version?

Comment: Maybe your main method contained `System.out.println("false")` before, and now you changed the code, but forgot to recompile the class.

Comment: @JBNizet nope I never had `false` in there. I just deleted the package and class and wrote the code again as well and still same output

Comment: Something is wrong on your side. There is no way for a loop printing integers to output "false".

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in forEach loop. It should be:

```
for (Integer j : coins) {
           // System.out.println(coins.get(j));
            System.out.println(j);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `j` will be the value of every element of `coins`, not the value of the index as in javascript.

Use:

```
for (Integer j : coins) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Or worse in many ways:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(coins.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
for (Integer j : coins)
```

It's like doing:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> itr = coins.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
   Integer j = itr.next();
}
```

As you can see, `j` has already the value you want.

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for more details.